# how to update only one field instead creating another object - django 1.4

Tags: python, django

I am trying to update the object instead of creating a new one. i have information and i want to check if this information already exist in db, even if with some differences in fields which means that the new information in my hand is the same as the one db, but only some fields are coming new -> so i only need to update that object.

```
location, created = Location.objects.get_or_create(**loc_fields)
if created:
   num_of_new_locs+=1 #number of new locations increased
else:
   location.url= loc_fields['url']
   location.locationname = loc_fields['locationname']
   location.desc = loc_fields['desc']
   location.str_hnr = loc_fields['str_hnr']
   location.save()
```

but this code is creating always new objects. my problem is, i dont know in advance which field might have changed. thats why i do this: If locationname or url are changed, i create new object, otherwise i will update the existing one..

how can i do this? `create_or_update` or `update_fields` is only in 1.7dev, i guess.

what is the best way of doing this in django1.4?

Comment: If you don't know which fields have changed, there's no way you'll be able to retrieve the object passing in all of the possible key/value pairs. If even one of those fields is different, the lookup will fail - that's why you're getting new objects. I would recommend looking up the Location object by a parameter that isn't going to change, like the ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work as expected if you're looking up a `Location` by a unique identifier instead of trying to match all fields:

```
location, created = Location.objects.get_or_create(pk=pk)
if created:
   num_of_new_locs+=1 #number of new locations increased
else:
   location.url= loc_fields['url']
   location.locationname = loc_fields['locationname']
   location.desc = loc_fields['desc']
   location.str_hnr = loc_fields['str_hnr']
   location.save()
```

Comment: thanks, Brandon. so i will have to delete the old versions then thru admin.

Comment: Bitte, und Ja, Sie werden.

Comment: Nein, ich bin kein Deutscher, aber meine Großmutter war. Ich spreche ein bisschen Deutsch.

Comment: Achso. Schön schön. :)  übrigens,bald brauche ich dich wieder fuer cms